# Merge and Renumber Pages with ITextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, merge, itext

We are trying to merge two page numbered PDFs into a new PDF. We want to have the new PDF start with the page number from 1 e.g.

1. PDF pages are sorted like this 1,2,3,4,5
2. PDF pages are sorted like this 1,2,3,4,5

Merged PDF should have the page number 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and other old page labels should not be seen on the newly merged PDF.

This is our sample code but Labels are not showing on page.

```
string output_file = "~/output/output.pdf";
Document document = new Document();
using (var inputPdfStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Test.pdf", FileMode.Open))
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputPdfStream);
    PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;

    using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(Server.MapPath(output_file), FileMode.Create)))
    {
        document.Open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
        PdfImportedPage page;

        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            page =writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
            document.NewPage();
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
            PdfPageLabels oLabel = new PdfPageLabels();
            oLabel.AddPageLabel(i, PdfPageLabels.DECIMAL_ARABIC_NUMERALS);
            writer.PageLabels = oLabel;
        }

        document.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing page labels (which are some sorts of page metadata shown for example by Adobe Reader in the `page` box on top of the document) and page numbers (which are written directly in the document, like any other piece of text in said document)?

Comment: I think Alexis is right. The question should be classified as "unanswerable."

Comment: Oh sorry ! Yes we just realized that.We thought that PageLabel is same with the page number. Do you have any opinion changing the rendred page number in a pdf?

Comment: For that you'll have to know the absolute position of the page number, and stamp the updated page number upon it.